# How to have EMRFS consistent view on S3 buckets with retention policy?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I am using an AWS EMR compute cluster (version 5.27.0) , which uses S3 for data persistence.
This cluster both reads and writes to S3.

S3 has an issue of [eventual consistency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel), because of which after writing data, it cannot be immediately listed. Due to this I use [EMRFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-consistent-view.html) with DynamoDB to store newly written paths for immediate listing.

Problem now is that I have to set a retention policy on S3, because of which data more than a month old will get deleted from S3. However, in doing so , the data does not get deleted from EMRFS DynamoDB table, leading to consistency issues.

My question is , how can I ensure that on setting the retention policy in S3, the same paths get deleted from the DynamoDB table?

One naive solution I have come up with is to define a Lambda, which fires periodically, and sets TTL of say 1 day on the DynamoDB records manually. Is there a better approach than this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure DynamoDB with same expiration policy as your S3 objects have

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-manage-dynamodb-items-using-time-to-live-ttl/

and in this case, you ensure both DynamoDB and S3 have the same existing objects

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the DynamoDB table is created by EMRFS. Not by the user. And it might happen that the table gets deleted.

Comment: even EMR DynamoDB can be configured with TTL, please check deletionTTL attribute: https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Migrating_to_Apache_Hbase_on_Amazon_S3_on_Amazon_EMR.pdf

Comment: "This support is only be applied to objects deleted from the metadata.To enable TTL for each metadata object marked as delete, apply the following emrfs-site.xmlproperties and execute the configuration steps to enable TTL support."

I did try this, and it can be only done for objects which are marked as deleted by EMRFS. In my case the objects will be deleted due to s3 retention policy.